# Split String input from file into an array using scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have a textfile that i am reading out of that looks like this:

```
pizza, fries, eggs.
1, 2, 4.
```

I am scannning this .txt using the Scanner class and i want to insert the input into an ArrayList. I know that there is a method to split Strings and use the `","` as a Delimiter but i cannot seem to find how and where to apply this. Note: The `.` is used as its own Delimiter so the scanner know it needs to check the next Line and add that to a different ArrayList.

Here is my corresponding code from the class with the ArrayList Setup:

```
public class GrocerieList {

    static ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> foodAmount = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And here is the code from the class scanning the .txt input:

```
public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        scan.useDelimiter("/|\\.");
        scan.nextLine(); // required because there is one empty line at .txt start

        if(scan.hasNext()) {
            GrocerieList.foodList.add(scan.next());
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        if(scan.hasNext()) {
            GrocerieList.foodAmount.add(scan.next());
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Where can i split the strings? And how? Perhaps my approach is flawed and i need to alter it? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you realize this will only process 1 line of data?

Comment: Ahh yes - i have rewritten it several times while trying to find a solution. Needs to be adjusted but that isn't my main concern as thats an easy fix. Still, my bad for posting flawed code! Sorry and thanks for the heads up Scott :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nextLine()` to read a line from the file, then eliminate the ending period, and split on comma.

And use *try-with-resources* to close the file correctly.

```
public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.nextLine(); // required because there is one empty line at .txt start
        GrocerieList.foodList.addAll(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().replaceFirst("\\.$", "").split(",\\s*")));
        GrocerieList.foodAmount.addAll(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().replaceFirst("\\.$", "").split(",\\s*")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Intellij tells me that it "Cannot resolve method 'toList" in 'Arrays'?

Comment: @Rebellinho Try `asList` instead?

Comment: Oops! Fixed. Thanks, Nexevis.

Comment: However if i use asList it works like a charm! Thank you Andreas :) you saved my day - and considering how long it wouldve taken me to find this info otherwise, probably also big chunks of my weekend! Cheers

Comment: Yes - exactly! Thanks Nexevis!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would save the read out from the `nextLine` method, and use the `split` method to decompose the list into an array, then store it to your target. If conversion is needed, such as from string to integer, do it separately.

```
  String lineContent = scan.nextLine();
  String[] components = lineContent.split(","); //now your array has "pizza", "fries", "eggs" etc.
```

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the ending period.

Comment: You are right, for that specific case need to do preprocessing before splitting

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use String#split.
Also you don't want 'next', but nextLine

`GrocerieList.foodList.addAll(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().replaceFirst("\\.$", "").split(", ")));`

(Should work but didn't test it).

For more informations about the scanner class refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the ending period.

Comment: You're right, sorry forgot that the delimiter isn't replaced when using scanners